# Unusual CSS specificity behaviour

Tags: css, css-specificity

I've worked with CSS for ages and I thought I understood specificity well, but this example baffles me; it's late at night so I might be missing something obvious:

```css
.class span {
  color: blue;
}

section#id {
  color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <section id="id">
    <span>Test</span>
  </section>
</div>
```

[**Specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) for `section#id` is 101, while for `.class span` is 11 and, on top of that, the second rule is even specified after the first one.

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't targeting the span with the second selector. The color will only cascade to elements where the color property is set to `inherit` (default).

Comment: Thanks, that was a really obvious thing as I was thinking. I just am really tired, thank you for clearing up my head.

Comment: @NinGenShinRa no worries!

Answer (score 3):

The first rule is narrowed to the span tag. The second rule is a higher level, at the parent section. So, yes, `.class span` will take precedence because it's hitting the actual tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted Christian's answer because it was more specific (pun intended) to my problem.

Comment: No worries, glad your issue was resolved in any case :)

Comment: Yup: I mean, the issue was really easy to solve, I just had one of those *"I have no idea why this is working"* moments, you know? ;)